# Как лучше организовать ООП код для движка сайта на php?

Tags: php, ооп, архитектура, инспекция-кода

Добрый день, уважаемые! Вот задался целью переписать самописный движок одного из своих сайтов, максимально используя ООП возможности PHP, так как существующий код до такой степени кривой (начал изучение php и одновременно делал сайт), что в последнее время любые изменения приходится вносить, неистово танцуя с бубнами :). Вот набросал такую точку входа, буду рад любой критике и предложениям:

```
<?php
/*
 *  Регистрируем ф-ю автозагрузки классов 
 */
spl_autoload_register( function ( $class ) 
    {
        $filename = "md_inc/class/".$class.".php";

        if( file_exists( $filename ) )
        {
            include_once $filename;
        }
    });

/* Установим уровень оповещения об ошибках */
if( MD_Config::DEBUG ) // MD_Config - у меня класс, который содержит все константы сайта, которые можно (и нужно) изменять в случае необходимости
{
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
}
else 
{
    error_reporting( ~E_ALL );
}
try 
{
    $md_site = new MD_Site();  // Вся остальная работа по инициализации и отображению сайта ложится на плечи конструктора класса MD_Site (правильное решение или лучше как-нибудь иначе??)
}
catch ( Exception $e )
{
    if( MD_Config::DEBUG )
    {
        echo "<pre>".$e."</pre>"; // Прототип обработки исключений
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Fatal error (".$e->getCode()."): ".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Также интересно, как лучше всего обработать ошибки, я решил использовать только механизм запуска исключений внутри классов, может зря?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый главный совет - максимально абстрагируйте отдельные части движка. Сделайте отдельный класс для автозагрузки, роутера, инициализации и проч. На мой взгляд точка входа должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(['autoloader','load']);
/* еще несколько  методов автозагрузки*/ 
//инициализация всей фигни движка
core::init();
// роутер
router::start();
```

Насчет обработки исключений - не зря, это довольно удобно. Собственный обработчик исключений можно установить так:

```
set_exception_handler('my_handler');
```

Comment: spl_autoload_register(['autoloader','load']);
Не совсем понял, что у Вас за аргумент, мое IDE выдает синтаксическую ошибку.
Возможно вы имели ввиду:
    
    spl_autoload_register(array('autoloader','load');

autoloader - это класс, а load его метод. Не совсем понимаю применение этой ф-и для нескольких автозагрузчиков, а в документации как-то это все слишком скудно описано, может знаете какую-нибудь дельную книгу или статью по этой теме?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/136761/ - статья по теме.

Насчет синтаксиса - [] вот так можно инициализировать массив начиная с php 5.4. у Вас вероятно версия ниже.